# How to safely repair this lightbulb holder/socket with threaded attachment?

Tags: wiring, lighting, socket, light-bulb

I have a hanging bulb holder near my bunk bed and I sometimes accidentally hit this holder when sleeping on the top bunk. Unfortunately, the holder is now detached from the ceiling due to the occasional hits. It was attached with some kind of threaded base but I am not sure what this kind of holder is called and I can not find any resources about repairing it. The tension to keep the bulb hanging is now on the wire itself instead of the threaded attachment it had previously.

The fixture has been like this for a while and bulbs does not show signs or flickering. However, I am not sure how dangerous this kinds of breakage is and the risks of repairing it myself. I tried reattaching the treads but the threads attached on the ceiling does not seem to stay in place. The base thread also rotates when I try to rotate the holder's thread to affix it. Below are some photos of the holder's attachment.

[image: detail of pendulum light socket]

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to remove the fixture from the ceiling but turn the power off first. With the fixture removed, you can grasp the threaded pipe and secure it to the holder. Examine the wires to make sure you didn't damage them with the holder hanging from the fixture. then reattach th fixture to the ceiling.

Since you have hit the fixture in the past, you might want to consider getting a new, smaller LED fixture and just replace the one you have.